# Pasar información desde el backend a una pagina estática, nodejs a javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy utilizando una API llamada Tesseract que transforma la información de una imagen ya sea palabras o números a texto y quiero enviar ese texto al frontend, a una pagina estática para manejarlo con js, ¿Cómo lo hago?, he intentado con res.json(variable), pero no me funciona.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
let hola; // <------- variable donde almaceno el texto
const path = require('path');
const {createWorker} = require("tesseract.js");
const worker = createWorker({
  logger: m => console.log(m)
});

(async ()=>{
    await worker.load();
    await worker.loadLanguage("eng");
    await worker.initialize("eng");
    const {data: {text} } = await worker.recognize(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'tesseract3/images', 'pruebareal.png')); // <------------ se carga la imagen desde una carpeta del directorio
    hola = text; // <------ Aquí pongo el texto en la variable hola
    await worker.terminate();
})();

app.use(express.static('public')); // <------------ cargar la pagina estática

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    const datos = hola.split(" "); // <---- separo los datos para convertirlo en un arreglo y manejarlo
    res.json(datos)  // <------- enviar los datos a la pagina en formato JSON
});



app.get("*",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/error404.html');
});

app.listen(8080,()=>console.log("aplicacion iniciada en puerto 8080"));
```

Soy nuevo en esto y no estoy muy seguro de cómo se envían datos desde [node](/questions/tagged/node), sé que normalmente se utiliza para manejar datos de usuarios y se pueden enviar desde un formulario, y ese tipo de cosas pero ahora solo quiero enviar datos creados desde el **backend** (*nodeJS*) al **forntend** (*JS*) para posteriormente manipularlos.

En teoría entraría algo como esto en la imagen
55.55 22.22 36.00 50.00

Y debería salir algo como esto

```
hola(5){...}
```

Comment: Lo unico que he podrido encontrar es que genere un archivo de texto el modulo fs de node, para luego abrirlo con un input de tipo file y de ahi manipularlo, pero esperaba algo mas simple.

Comment: En principio, el concepto de *enviar* desde NodeJS sólo es válido cuando se ha realizado una petición desde el cliente. Dicho esto, es tan sencillo como crear una llamada `ajax` desde el cliente (mediante algún botón, o incluso un `link`) y manejar la respuesta (lo que envías) de NodeJS. ¿Podrías aclarar un poco lo que pretendes lograr con esto? Saludos

Comment: utilizar los datos enviados desde node para guardarlos en javascript del lado del cliente y manipularlos, sumar restar dividir lo que sea, es todo.

Comment: Vale, pero recuerda, que el servidor no envía nada, a menos que el cliente se lo pida, excepto si usas un sistema de comunicación bidireccional, como `sockets` por ejemplo. Saludos